# pygame - python getting variables with the visiter pattern

Tags: variables, methods, pygame, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to use the visiter pattern to get self.coin value from the first class and return it to the method in the second class but its not working, its always returning none... can anyone help?

```
class coin_collector(Observer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Observer, self).__init__()
        self.coin_count = 0
        self.run = True
        self.coin = 0

    def acceptVisitor(self, visitor):
        visitor.visit(self)

    def update(self, observable, other):
        me = coin_collector()
        me.coin_Count(other, True)

    def coin_Count(self, value, TF):
        run = TF
        if run:
            self.coin = value
            print self.coin
        return self.coin

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

#this is part of a different class in a different file 
    def visit(self, location):
        location.coin_Count(0, False)

    def update(self):
        visitee = coin_collector()
        self.c_Count = self.visit(visitee) # for some reason this always returns none
        print self.c_Count, "working" # this always prints none...
```

Comment: what are you expecting to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's start with `Coin Collector`. His `coin` attribute is set to 0.
You also have a second class with an `update` and `visit` function.

The update function creates a **new** `coin_collector` at every call. Then it assigns the return value of `visit` function to `self.c_Count`. Let's now see the `visit` function.

It takes in a brand new `coin collector` and returns **None** It would assign its value parameter to the `coin` field if you would pass `True` as `TF`.

After coming back from `coin_count` function, you do not do anything in the `visit` function so the return value is lost. That is why, when you try to assign the result of `self.visit`, you get a `None`.